# MySQL trigger doesn`t work with NEW but static

Tags: mysql, triggers

I created a MySQL-Trigger within phpmyadmin:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trig_update_post_commentdate`
AFTER INSERT ON `tx_domain_model_comment`
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE `tx_domain_model_post`
SET `commentdate` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE uid = NEW.post
```

But this doesn't work.

If I replace `NEW.post` with a static value like `1848`, it works.

So how can I get the value of the inserted row of the column post?

Thanks a lot for an answer!

Comment: The code is correct. Can you show your tables (CREATE TABLE statements)?

Comment: Here are the CREATE TABLE statements:

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tx_domain_model_comment` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `commentdate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `tstamp` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `crdate` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cruser_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
....
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tx_domain_model_post` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `viewcount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `postdate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `forum_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `tstamp` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
..
  `commentdate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Have checked your schema. Everything is working. I had been thinking that virtual (calculate) column was the reason, but you do not have them.

Comment: Check that `tx_domain_model_post` contains corresponded records - where tx_domain_model_post.uid = tx_domain_model_comment.post.

Comment: First, thank you very much for your efforts.

Yes, there are corresponding records.

I just tried:
UPDATE `tx_domain_model_post`
SET `commentdate` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE uid = NEW.uid

and it worked too.

So what`s wrong with NEW.post???

Comment: Very strange. Can you add full script to reproduce?